# How to show nested dictionaries in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have dynamics field and I need the CSV file shows field in its column, you can see in this image, the dynamic fields shows literals {} brackets and show all of them in one row, [image]I need to separte in each column I don't care if father header is duplicate for each dynamic field (JOB_INSIGHTS FOR INSTANCE). I want every nested dict element in its own column. Thanks in advance!!

updating:
the output plicated got with the following code:
dict example:

```
my_list_didct= [{
    "main_rating": "7",
    "job_salary": "$51K",
    "job_insights": {
        "Job Type : ": "Full-time",
        "Job Function : ": "Software Developer",
    "aditional_salaries":{"dev_ops":"$44k",
                          "sysadmin":"$30k"}
    }]


    try:
        ruta_guardado = os.path.join(out_path_file,
                                     'file_{today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}_{readfrom_text_file('dat')}.csv")
        with open(
                ruta_guardado, mode, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            csv.register_dialect('myDialect',
                                 delimiter=';',
                                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            print(items)
            headers = list(items[0].keys())
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers, dialect="myDialect")
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            my_logger.info(items)
            csv_writer.writerows(items)
```

in the example on top aditional salaries is not always found, sometimes return empty dict, in that case I would like a excel field empty. or if exists spread like the rest of fields which are str instead a dict. :L thank you coders.

kind of output I'm looking for.
[image]

Comment: Don't you want to consider a `json` instead?

Answer (score 0):

First, You can't save a `dict` into into `.csv` file without converting it into a **DataFrame**. So, you need to convert it into a **DataFrame** then save it into whatever file you want to save

Also, if you don't have a file and you just write the name and the format of the file, it will immediately save it.

**Code Syntax**

```
import pandas as pd

my_list_didct= [{
    "main_rating": "7",
    "job_salary": "$51K",
    "job_insights": {
        "Job Type : ": "Full-time",
        "Job Function : ": "Software Developer",
    "aditional_salaries":{"dev_ops":"$44k",
                          "sysadmin":"$30k"}
    }}]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_didct)
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: sorry if I did'nt express myself clear, I'm trying to save, in CSV file a dict python with nested fields. JSON is not what I need, JSON writes correct. problem is csv :L thankyou in advanced! :D

Comment: Use `df.to_csv()`

Comment: thanks @Dr.Xavier I use to_csv() method from panda but the output is the same! :L

Comment: Its good that you share the `dict` with us. Let me run it and edit my answer

Comment: check your entered dict, it's missing `}` at the end

Comment: @Miguel check the answer again

Comment: hello my friend, yep,but the dict before it's just an example , you can see the output with panda is the same that dicWriter object shared on top top. I don't know wheater treat as NOT DICT field, arrange them before the exportation or keep finding the output I looking for (shared now), would you recommend a best and clean way to represent that dinamic dict fields without that ugly brackets and colons? jaja, which ones could has info and other just return an empty dict. thanks again for helping me :D

Comment: I think you will have to arrange everything before saving it into csv file, like creating a subset of these sub column, you will need to google how can you create sub-columns i think

Comment: I'm finally thinking about arrange items into non dict fields, I mean spread dynnamic fields in static headers, and items with no dynamic field print empty value, the sheet will be fatter but clean to read which is my main target , I appreciate your help brother!.